# How to Download File with a GET in URL using wget?

Tags: linux, command-line

How do I download a file given a URL like so: https://courses.cs.ca/2013fa-cmpt-100-d1/+gems/submission/ass1/145678/get

Answer (score 1):

`wget 'https://courses.cs.ca/2013fa-cmpt-100-d1/+gems/submission/ass1/145678/get'`

If you want to specify a filename for the downloaded file, add `-O filename`.

Comment: Hey, the problem with that is I only end up downloading an html page instead of an actual file. The link works such that if I copy paste it into my browser, I immediately get a download prompt.

Comment: @Rob When using wget, it will download the file that the link is pointing to. In your case the file that it is pointing to is an HTML file that instructs your browser to begin a download.

Comment: @Moses Yes, I am aware of this. Is there a way so that I can download the file using the command line?

Comment: @Rob You would have to know the actual location of the file in question, then use wget. You might be able to find out if you download the HTML file pointing to it, and open the source code.